# What is usefulness of time series decomposition if building a multivariate model?

Tags: time-series, trend, seasonality

I am at the early stages of building a panel regression model of sales data. I know my final model dataset will consist of log sales, control variables and log media variables.
I am planning to use stl() to decompose the log sales time series.

My question:

If I am going to create a multivariate time series model anyway, does it make sense to decompose the dependent variable during the Exploratory Data Analysis (EDA) phase?

Does the seasonal/ trend component in the decomp tell me something about my timeseries different than I would expect controlling for these factors on the RHS of the model equation?

Comment: I think you should write out some equations, to make your reference to "the RHS" clearer.